# Class that takes in an iterator when initialized and only returns certain objects. Ruby

Tags: ruby, linked-list, iterator, subclass, each

I just started learning ruby a couple of weeks ago and am working on an assignment and there is a part I am unclear about.
Background: So I have Student objects(has student name, GPA, ID) that go into Nodes . Then a doubly Linkedlist class where those node objects go.

I am suppose to create a class called probation_filter(iterator) that takes in an iterator when it is initialized and it should just iterate through the linked list and return the students that are "on probation" which means have a gpa of less than 2.7.

Within that class, I may have methods equivalent to Java's hasNext() and next() if needed.

I'm just not exactly sure how to go about this. This is my guess: So in my LinkedList class I have iterating methods each and reverse_each instead of actual iterator objects.

So would I do:

```
class OnProbationFilter
    def initialize(iterator)
        @each=iterator
       //condition to filter and return students that have a GPA of less than 2.7
    end
     //other methods that class may need    
end
```

**Should the condition to filter out the students on probation all actually happen inside the constructor?**

**Also, how would I call this method in the linkedlist? Would I INCLUDE probation_filter in the LinkedList class and then do something like declare new Linkedlist probation_list variable, then call the probation_filter(each), pass in the each and store it into the new probation_list?**

LinkedList probation_list= new OnProbationFilter(each)//pseudo code

Comment: Is there any reason to have the student objects as linked lists? Will you show the code for the nodes and linked list?

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually return anything from your constructor.

Or you could store off the iterator passed in then implement a function something like this:

```
def each()
  @each.select { |student|  student.GPA > 2.7  }.each do |record|
    yield record
  end
end
```